# How do you backup CRM3.0 when the 'ftcat_documentindex' is offline?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, backup

My organisation uses Microsoft CRM 3.0, and I am attempting to backup the database. The following error is preventing me from doing so, does anyone know how to resolve this issue?

**Error:**

System.Data.SqlClient.SqlError: The backup of full-text catalog 'ftcat_documentindex' is not permitted because it is not online. Check errorlog file for the reason that full-text catalog became offline and bring it online. Or BACKUP can be performed by using the FILEGROUP or FILE clauses to restrict the selection to include only online data.  (Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo)

For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&ProdVer=9.00.4035.00&LinkId=20476

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error states, you can either do a [filegroup backup](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179401.aspx) or you can bring the full text data catalog online.  You can identify the location of the fulltext catalog (or at least, where it's supposed to be), using the following:

```
SELECT  sf.filename
FROM    sys.fulltext_catalogs ftc
JOIN    sys.sysfiles sf ON ftc.[file_id] = sf.fileid
```

If your catalog isn't there, perhaps it was deleted.  You could manually recreate it, or there is likely a utility within MSCRM to rebuild it - you may need to contact your reseller for help with that though.

Comment: I'm currently rebuilding the full-text database in attempt to fix the issue.  If that fails i'll try this method. Thanks :)